# How to properly use the grep command to grab and store integers?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am currently building a bash script for class, and I am trying to use the grep command to grab the values from a simple calculator program and store them in the variables I assign, but I keep receiving a syntax error message when I try to run the script. Any advice on how to fix it? my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

addanwser=$(grep -o "num1 + num2" Lab9 -a 5 2)
echo "addanwser"

subanwser=$(grep -o "num1 - num2" Lab9 -s 10 15)
echo "subanwser"

multianwser=$(grep -o "num1 * num2" Lab9 -m 3 10)
echo "multianwser"

divanwser=$(grep -o "num1 / num2" Lab9 -d 100 4)
echo "divanwser"

modanwser=$(grep -o "num1 % num2" Lab9 -r 300 7)
echo "modawser"`
```

Comment: What is `Lab9`? what do you get if you say just `Lab9 -a 5 2`? Give that output so we can understand the question better. To me it looks like you want to do `grep -o "num1 + num2" "$(Lab -a 5 2)"`.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? It should appear (preceeded by ">") in your question.

Comment: plus you have an extra ` at the end of your script(in `echo "modawser"\``), which could cause the issue.

Comment: Lab9 is the calculator program in which I am getting the integers I want to grab and store from, and the -a 5 2 part is the argument it means add 5 + 2, I want to store the output.

Comment: The error message I get says <invalid argument>

Comment: Unless _Lab9_ is a text data file, (not a program), _grep_ won't be much help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to `grep` the output of a command.

`grep` searches from either a file or standard input. So you can say either of these equivalent:

```
grep X file                 # 1. from a file
... things ... | grep X     # 2. from stdin
grep X <<< "content"        # 3. using here-strings
```

For this case, you want to use the last one, so that you execute the program and its output feeds `grep` directly:

```
grep <something> <<< "$(Lab9 -s 10 15)"
```

Which is the same as saying:

```
Lab9 -s 10 15 | grep <something>
```

So that `grep` will act on the output of your program. Since I don't know how `Lab9` works, let's use a simple example with `seq`, that returns numbers from 5 to 15:

```
$ grep 5 <<< "$(seq 5 15)"
5
15
```

Answer (score 0):

grep is usually used for finding matching lines of a text file. To actually grab a part of the matched line other tools such as awk are used.

Assuming the output looks like "num1 + num2 = 54" (i.e. fields are separated by space), this should do your job:

```
addanwser=$(Lab9 -a 5 2  | awk '{print $NF}')
echo "$addanwser"
```

Make sure you don't miss the '$' sign before addanwser when echo'ing it.
$NF selects the last field. You may select nth field using $n.